# Azure Cloud Service Deployment

Tags: azure, deployment, cloud

I am having an issue deploying to the Staging environment of my Windows Azure Cloud Service.
This is something I do frequently without issue before doing a swap to Production (once I have validated everything is OK in Staging). Today for some reason I am getting this error when trying to deploy:

> Allocation failed; unable to satisfy constraints in request. The requested new service deployment is bound to an Affinity Group, or it targets a Virtual Network, or there is an existing deployment under this hosted service. Any of these conditions constrains the new deployment to specific Azure resources. Please retry later or try reducing the VM size or number of role instances. Alternatively, if possible, remove the aforementioned constraints or try deploying to a different region. The long running operation tracking ID was: da5cc14aaba6228683cb4e8888b835e1.

Seeing as my deployment package has not changed since the last time I successfully performed an update of my Staging environment (apart from one line of code for a bug fix) I can't see this being an issue with my package. I am hoping this is transient Azure environment issue - anyone any ideas as to what this may be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a fragmentation issue in the cluster you are trying to deploy to.  The ops team is engaged and working to resolve and you should be able to deploy again later tonight or tomorrow.

Some additional information:

1. Once you create a deployment (either prod or staging slot) in a cloud service your entire cloud service (both prod and staging slots) are pinned to a cluster of machines (there are some Mark Russinovich fabric videos with more details if you are interested).  So if there is a problem in a cluster, or you try to deploy a VM size not available in the cluster such as the new D series machines, then you may fail if the specific cluster can't allocate the request.  To resolve this you can deploy to a brand new cloud service which will allow the fabric to check all clusters in that datacenter/region to satisfy the allocation request.
2. Consider a different upgrade strategy for scenarios like this.  A lot of services will upgrade by creating a new deployment in a new cloud service, thus getting a new URL and IP address, and then modify the CNAME or A Record in order to transition clients to the new service.
3. If you see this issue again you can usually get a fast resolution by opening a support incident - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/

Update: We have a new blog post that describes this scenario and the common causes - http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/03/19/allocation-failure-and-remediation/.

Comment: Thank you, I see from your profile that you know what you are talking about! I still can't deploy this morning but yesterday I adopted step 2 and created a new Cloud Service and modified my CNAME. I still have my original service - are you saying that at some point today when the issue is fixed I should be able to re-deploy to my original service?

Comment: @kwill - does this have the potential to cause failures during autoscaling too? And does clearing the deployments from a CS but not deleting the CS itself permit reallocation to a new cluster?

Comment: Hi Graham.  Yes, this will affect scaling (autoscaling or manual scaling).  And yes, if you delete both the production and staging slots, but not the cloud service, then you can redeploy into that same cloud service and the fabric will pick a new cluster.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar **allocation failed** issue recently deploying our **Azure Cloud Service**:

#### Azure Cloud Service Deployment Error

> Allocation failed; unable to satisfy constraints in request. The requested new service deployment is bound to an Affinity Group, or it targets a Virtual Network, or there is an existing deployment under this hosted service. Any of these conditions constrains the new deployment to specific Azure resources. Please retry later or try reducing the VM size or number of role instances. Alternatively, if possible, remove the aforementioned constraints or try deploying to a different region.

#### Allocation Failed - Resolution

1. Delete Existing Cloud Service
2. Create New Cloud Service target different **Data Center** or **Resource Group** (*upload SSL certs required*)
3. Redeploy cloud service package
4. Relink VSO Team Projects

I suspect the issue has something to do with a corrupt resource group or recent Azure upgrades that were not backwards compatible with older resource groups.